# Simple Code in Python to change the Upper Case and Lower Case

Tags: python, python-3.x, uppercase, lowercase

I want to use the *args to input the name and change the even numbers for the character to Upper Case and odd number character to lower case. For example, `Myname` -> `MyNaMe`

I used the following code for the operation. But it is output all the characters as upper case. (If I add any random variable under myfunc1(x), then it is working properly.)

Using *args :

```py
def myfunc1(*args):
    result=''
    for i in range(0,len(args)):
        if i%2==0:
            result+=args[i].upper()
        else:
            result+=args[i].lower()
    print(result)

myfunc1('My Name') # prints "MY NAME"
```

Using random Variable:

```py
def myfunc1(my_string):
    result=''
    for i in range(0,len(my_string)):
        if i%2==0:
            result+=my_string[i].upper()
        else:
            result+=my_string[i].lower()
    print(result)

myfunc1('Myname') # prints MyNaMe
```

Comment: *args can be a list of arguments. You're sending one argument 'My Name'. It can be more than that too like 'My Name's, 'Your Name'. So when you do args[i] you just get each args, in this case 'My Name'. You need to apply that logic you've applied inside another loop.

Comment: Why you used ``*args`` and passed a ``string`` to your function? ``myfunc1('My Name', 'str1', 'str2')`` this is the usage of ``*args``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args` is a list of arguments. Since you're sending 1 argument, `args=('My Name',)`.

Correct code

```py
def myfunc1(*args):
    result=''
    for i in range(0,len(args[0])):
        if i%2==0:
            result+=args[0][i].upper()
        else:
            result+=args[0][i].lower()
    print(result)

myfunc1('My Name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing the `args` variable with `*`. That means you are passing a list of arguments. So, when you write `myfunc1('My Name')`, the function is getting as argument the string `'My Name'` and an empty argument. So, when you iterate args, the first for will work over 'My name' and the second for will work over the empty argument. The solution is simple, remove the `*` from the declaration of your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your string like this:

**Code:**

```py
def myfunc1(my_string):
    print(''.join([char.upper() if idx % 2 == 0 else char.lower() for idx, char in enumerate(my_string)]))

myfunc1("My Name")
```

**Output:**

```py
> My nAmE
```